# "Already exists" error notification

Tags: error-message, error-prevention

I have a dialog box telling the user to upload new pictures, but if one picture already exists there is a notification telling the user this information and he have to remove it himself. The problem is that all uploaded pictures have a green checking-sign, like so:

[image]

This of course has to be improved. There should at least not be a green check-sign if the picture already exists.

[image]

But is there a way to prevent the error? I don’t want the user to make the error in the first place, and absolutely not having to correct it himself.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question what the user might want in this situation: Cancel the upload because it is already done?  Upload the second picture with a deduplicated name?  Replace the previous picture?  More information on the use case would help here.

Comment: It is also not clear what counts as "already exists"? Is this if there is a duplicate file name only? Or are you checking image dimensions, bytes and/or a checksum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the approach in Windows and OS X when copying files/folders?

Validate before the file is uploaded, and give the option to the user what they want to do with duplicates: **replace**, **skip**, or **rename/keep both**.

#### Windows 8

[image: Windows 8]

### OS X

[image: OS X]

Comment: Great reply. This would both give the user a "positive" kind of feedback, while keeping an easy and user-friendly UI.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in any validation process, the validation should be taken **before** the action performed. So, you have to check for file existence before uploading process, then cancel the upload for the existing file and notify the uploader.